# Expressing the speed up of one algorithm over another as a function of input size

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, time-complexity

I have two matrix multiplication algorithms - one more efficient than the other - and have measured the speed of both when calculating the product of two `N`x`N` matrices for `N = [500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]`.

I would now like to show the general improvement in speed as a  function of `N`. How can I do this?

Comment: does this help: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: I am aware of Big O notation, but am just unsure as how to compare the two algorithms. Based on my small dataset, the both seem to grow quite exponentially, but the more efficient one less so than the other.

Comment: While it's possible with small data sets that one algorithm can be significantly faster than another with the same big O, I would start with calculating Big O for both: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194433/is-this-a-proper-rule-for-identifying-the-big-o-notation-of-an-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You can fit a curve to the ratio of the runtime of the fast one to the runtime of the slow one; the resulting curve will give you the speedup as a function of input size.

In order for this to be really useful, I would recommend you identify the best and worst cases for each algorithm; so you have four sets identified:

- best case for fast algorithm
- worst case for fast algorithm
- best case for slow algorithm
- worst case for slow algorithm

Ideally, the best cases and worst cases are the same, in which case you can bound the speedup by taking (best case slow) / (best case fast) and (worst case slow) / (worst case fast).

Realistically, there may be non-negligible classes of inputs which represent:

- a best case for the fast algorithm, and a worst case for the slow algorithm
- a worst case for the fast algorithm, and a best case for the slow algorithm

In this case, your actual bounds will be (worst case slow) / (best case fast) and (best case fast) / (worst case slow).

Note that what matters is that you've identified coherent classes and you are comparing apples to apples - that is, any function you give is comparing the algorithms using the same case. You need to fully understand each individual algorithm to understand the best and worst case behavior of the ratio of the two.